# Enable hardware virtualization causes crash

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, motherboard, bios, intel-core-i7

Every time I enable hardware virtualization in my BIOS and restart my PC will load just past the showing of the Asus logo then shuts down. It will keep restarting my PC trying to load, and fails every time, but when it is disabled there are no problems.

Windows will not load when I enable this the PC goes into a restarting over and over loop.

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Mobo: Asus -z170-E
- CPU: i7-6700k - overclocked
- BIOS: Latest version 3801 - No new firmware showing. I am using the current version

Ram - 32 gigs running in xmp mode at 3000

Comment: What fails to load exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Virtualization is highly memory dependent. Please advsie your memory, and which virtualization system you use, by clicking [edit] to add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Restore the clock settings on your CPU back to the default non-overclocked settings. It would also be useful to enter the BIOS immediately after POST-ing when starting the computer to check the CPU temperature to determine if it's overheating.